# How do you give Reference of CallBack function in DaVinci configurator

Tags: communication, spi, can-bus, autosar, automotive

I am currently writing a Autosar Server CDD. The Motive of this CDD is to notify the Clients once the data available. So the flow will be like,

RX/TX line ---> Communication Driver ---> Communication Server ---> Clients

Here, planning to call the callback function of client from Communication server.

The configuration parameters for my CDD will be,

1. Callback function reference
2. Command Id (for which callback should be called)
3. Communication Channel from which the notification is expected
   At the runtime, plan is to for received notification, verify the received commandID and call the respective CallBack function configured for that commnadID.

Now I am confused about how to give the reference of callback function (it can be located in other CDD/SWC) in DaVinci configurator (PS. I am using Vectors tool chain for Autosar configurations).

Comment: And now, why the heck do you need that "Autosar Server CDD" exactly? Especially, since Autosar Com/LdCom + RTE + SWC already supports this. (DataReceivedEvent (Rx), DataReceiveErrorEvent (Rx),  DataSendCompletedEvent (Tx)). Together with Port/Data Mapping and you would not need that server CDD at all and also no command IDs. Maybe you guys should finally read and try to understand the specs and their concepts, like TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate (ch 4 & 7) and TPS_SystemTemplate (ch. 5, 6 & 7) EXP_LayeredSoftwareArchitecture, EXP_VFB and also SWS_RTE (mapping of templates to RTE generation).

Comment: @kesselhaus, I agree with you but we can not use it for  I2C/UART right? 
As per my understanding, we need to implement I2C/UART with the help CDD as these communication protocols are not standard autosar modules. 

So when any data is received, communication driver needs to notify and transfer it to clients/SWCs.

Comment: If this is pure communication (not an peripheral like ext. ADC) then you could: for UART/SCI use the LinDriver. Or create a CDD driver, that maps your CommandIDs to PDUs and vice versa. To the upper layer, you could use the RxIndication/TxIndication/Transmit interfacce, and connect them with PduR and use the rest like normal ComStack. Or you create for the different "commands" each an P-Port with S/R interface, which you connect then directly to SWC R-Port

Comment: Thanks for the response @kesselhaus, I will use the  RxIndication/TxIndication/Transmit interfaces to notify it to upper layer whne the data/message is received.